# assumption checks in ggstatsplot

Tags: r

I just discovered the ggstatspackage which is really amazing.

I wonder if there is a way to have assumptions checks for ANOVA or t-tests? (like levene test and shapiro tests)

Also, I wonder if there is a way to automatically remove outliers when performing the inferential statistics?

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. The assumptions you make when model fitting or identifying a sample as an outlier are dependent on a deep understanding of your data, where it came from, and what type of inference you want to make about your data. The practice of statistics has not yet been automated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I wonder if there is a way to have assumptions checks for ANOVA or t-tests? (like levene test and shapiro tests)

No. You can check out `{performance}` package to check model assumptions:

https://easystats.github.io/performance/reference/index.html#section-check-model-assumptions-or-properties

> Also, I wonder if there is a way to automatically remove outliers when performing the inferential statistics?

No, this is not possible. `{ggstatsplot}` provides two ways to deal with outliers:

- visually highlight them (using `outlier.tagging = TRUE`) in plots
- use robust statistics (`type = "robust"`), which is robust to presence of outliers